# Getting the Facebook creation date of a profile

Tags: php, security, facebook, authentication

Is it possible to get the creation date/time of a Facebook profile, through the use of the Graph API ?

I need it to make an authentication mechanism, that doesn't allow Facebook users that have just been created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Calling the Facebook API is a (relatively) slow operation; especially if you have to call it multiple times. So, when possible, it is a good idea to get the information you need, without making API calls.

You may take a look at http://metadatascience.com/2013/03/11/inferring-facebook-account-creation-date-from-facebook-user-id/. It explains how to figure out the creation date of a Facebook account without having to call the Facebook API, just based on the user’s Facebook UID.

Comment: This solution was the best, but i think it no longer works, since the introduction of app-scoped user-ids, more info here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. It helped me alot.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is'nt. The better way, and sounds a bit hackish, is to retrieve the users posts and keeping the oldest one as  an *estimate* of the user creation date!.

Keep in mind that is not always affordable. If you use /feed you get the latest 30days or 50 posts, if you use /posts , you get the authors posts. Remember that you must have *read_stream* permission.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) At least that's a pretty decent approximation, and should be enough for the use I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it. The [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) lists all the fields you can retrieve using the Graph API, and registration date isn't one of them. Come to think of it, the registration date disappeared from users' profiles sometime ago, about the same time the Graph API was introduced, maybe?

You can tell if one user registered earlier than another by looking at their user id, though. :)

Comment: Sorry, I mistakely downvoted you. Edit your message and I will revert that action. :-)

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert edit to change what?